# IF a function is assigned to a variable declared using var and let what is the difference?

Tags: javascript, function, var, let

when i run the code below it gives me error

```
var name = function print(){
console.log("welcome ......");
};
name();


js.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: name is not a function
at js.js:5
```

but when i change the var keyword to let then it runs fine 
Can anyone explain it please

```
let name = function print(){
console.log("welcome ......");
};
name();
```

Answer (score 3):

`name` is a predefined property in the JavaScript runtime that `set` or `get` the name of a window. So, you cannot use this reserved property as a function when using `var`.

The reason for this is `let` allows you to declare variables that are limited in scope to the block, statement, or expression on which it is used. This is unlike the `var` keyword, which defines a variable globally, or locally to an entire function regardless of block scope. So, when `var` tries to define `name` as a variable, `globally` in this case, it conflicts with the existing `name` property so you get that error while using `var` but not with `let`.

```js
//get name  value
console.log(name);
//set name value
name = 'someNewName';
console.log(name);
```

Thus, to make your code run, you need to change the function name to other name, say, `name1`:

```js
var name1 = function print(){
  console.log("welcome ......");
}
name1();
```

Comment: @JamilAmini glad to help

Comment: @giorgim added more detail in answer

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal makes sense but if I declare variable using `let` directly inside script e.g. without enclosing it say in function, isn't it also global then?

Comment: @giorgim it is limited in scope to the block which means only to that specific JS file and not the entire JavaScript environment

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal Ah and `var` means it is not only that file (if it is outside function or block say) but JS environment as whole, ok, got it.